# How do I resolve the -apptype missing error in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

> Error: Failed to generate web.config. Error: Attribute '-appType' is
>   missing in the Web.config parameters. Valid values for '-appType' are:
>   'python_Bottle', 'python_Django', 'python_Flask', 'node' and 'Go'.For example, '-appType python_Bottle' (sans-quotes) in case of
>   Python Bottle framework..

This error is happening in the Azure App Service Deploy Step of my pipeline.  The biggest oddity is that is a standard ASP.NET MVC application.

The solution does include multiple deployment packages but for this pipeline I am only deploying one of them and I specifically call this package out in the Package or Folder setting (SiteName.Zip)

Answer (score 3):

You've probably found the answer now, but for me it happened when upgrading from version 3 of the task to version 4. They've added an additional text field:

```
Generate web.config parameters for Python, Node.js, Go and Java apps
```

which now appears above the

```
JSON variable substitution
```

text box. When upgrading the task I somehow ended up with my json file name in the web.config box, which was causing this issue.